# redirect a subfolder from heroku to dedicated WordPress hosting

Tags: url, heroku, dns, harp

I have a simple site on heroku using Harp (not married to harp, just used something that can serve up static HTML.

We need to add a blog in a subfolder domain.com/blog instead of blog.domain.com for SEO reasons.  Is there a way on Heroku to redirect just a subfolder?

I don't want to host, manage or deal with WordPress in any fashion.  I'd like to avoid running any other blogging software.  My preference is just to leverage the hosting solutions without losing SEO scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to do the redirect in Harp, but unfortunately Harp doesn't support server-side redirects. You can do a [client-side redirect](https://harpjs.com/recipes/client-side-redirect), though.